# How to include an android AAR file in maven build

Tags: android, maven

I have created a simple android application using Maven build by following the steps given in this link :

http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=4137

By following the steps in the link I was able to create and deploy the android application and can see the output on emulator.

Now I am trying to add an existing AAR file as a dependency in my `Maven pom.xml` file. So I copied the AAR file which I am having to libs directory of my project.

After searching in internet I found this link on how to consume the AAR file in Maven -- https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AAR

It says that we can consume the AAR file by adding the dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.52</version>
    <type>aar</type>
  </dependency>
```

When I included this in my pom file then my maven build is failing with error message as :

Command Used -  `mvn clean install -e`

Error:

```
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.google.android.gms:play-services:aar:4.4.52 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Now if I use the -U option to get the updates then I am getting this error:

Command Used -  `mvn clean install -U -e`

Error:

```
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.google.android.gms:play-services:aar:4.4.52 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

I am completely new to android applications, can someone please help me on how to include the AAR file and build it using Maven?

Comment: Can anyone please help me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Android stopped uploading artifacts to Maven after Android 4.2, since they moved to gradle exclusively.  You can still install the aar to your local maven repo (using `mvn install:install-file` target). [Here's](https://gist.github.com/mpurbo/052ad9d0eb4aa3084b4b) an example of how to do it.